# How to import relative project with the Android Studio（not jar）

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

How to import relative project with the Android Studio or Intellij Idea（not jar）?For example,the opensource project ActionBarSherlock or Slidingmenu ect. They are not jars,but projects.If I want to use them for my own project,what should I do? (Used eclipse before)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16588104#16588104