# Module project as library in Android Studio causes rendering problems

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying a couple of times and tried different libraries (thought that problems lies there) and every time getting **Rendering problems**:

[image: Rendering problem]

This problem occurs when I try indicate that the listview is now a LoadMoreListView like in [this guide](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) of library.

in *layout/fragment_main.xml* file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have already tried different guides ([this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TForBjArUNg), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622410/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio-and-use-itsome-asked-dont)) and every time I'm getting these rendering problems.

---

How I did import:

So I put library into *app/libraries/'library here'*:

[image]

*`Settings.gradle`* file:

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:pulltorefresh-and-loadmore'
```

and in *app/build.gradle* file added dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
compile project('libraries:pulltorefresh-and-loadmore')
}
```

This project in [github](https://github.com/AnZyuZya/CurrentlyMaintained/tree/master/GithubViewer) if needed..

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a compile error when you build the project. The path you specify in the `compile project` statement must be the same as in your **settings.gradle** file. Change this:

```
compile project('libraries:pulltorefresh-and-loadmore')
```

to this:

```
compile project('app:libraries:pulltorefresh-and-loadmore')
```

Comment: ehm.. But I have exact that in `settings.gradle`.