# How do I structure my react-native JS code to have multiple android apps in the same project?

Tags: android, react-native

I just finished creating an android app in react-native (RN). I need to create another app now. A lot of code is same across both apps. I want to create the second app within the same project and reuse all the common components rather than duplicating them.

I went through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419621/can-we-have-multiple-apps-in-one-android-studio-project) and [configure android build variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419621/can-we-have-multiple-apps-in-one-android-studio-project) link. They talk about how to create a new module, gradle config and organization of java code in different source sets like src/demoDebug/, src/debug/, src/demo/ and src/main/.

I don't think this will work with react-native because the entry point of RN app is index.android.js. For 2 apps to work out of the same project we need 2 entry points. Is there a way to define multiple entry points in a RN android app? Does RN support this? If yes, how to organize files of the two apps in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create git submodule and move all shared code to it