# launch two different apk from one android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to launch two different android apps from one neutral project but the installed app will be only neutral one, and in that there will be two different buttons to launch(open in that app only) resp. project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have multiple apps in one Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419621/can-we-have-multiple-apps-in-one-android-studio-project)

Comment: see product flavors

Comment: you can you flavors : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDEK4wkN5I&t=322s

Answer (score -1):

you need use flavores in gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    defaultConfig {
       //...
    }

    buildTypes {
        //...
    }

    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            // config for app 1
        }
        app2 {
            // config for app 2
        }
    }

}



dependencies {
   //...
}
```

see this [link](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-product-flavors-1ef276b2bbc1) for learn about flavors