# Is it possible to add an existing project in new project/application?

Tags: java, android, project, android-camera2

I have an android project and I want to include in it, my camera project/application.
Is there any way to proceed without having to copy each and every file of my camera application in the new project?
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You need to right click on your project and add as new module (new project)

Comment: Thank you this worked! However my issue now is that when I launch the project it only launches only the camera app(new module) instead. Is there any way I could control which project will be the one launched first?

Comment: I found the answer to my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419621/can-we-have-multiple-apps-in-one-android-studio-project)!

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to do this is to launch your camera application installed on your device in your new project. i think you can launch it this way:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I want to have both projects in one.