# Can we have multiple apps in one Android Studio project

Tags: android

Can we have multiple apps in one Android Studio project

And move between them

Example

Intent intent = new Intent(The first project, the second project);

Comment: android studio is an IDE, it's what you use to develop your apps. that's all. after you've built your app, android studio becomes irrelevant. it's impossible to move between projects in android studio, because your phone isn't running android studio, it runs android as an OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have multiple apps in one Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419621/can-we-have-multiple-apps-in-one-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confused.  Android Studio is the IDE.  It is not the phone, you do not move between apps via Intent there.  You can have multiple apps in a single Android Studio project, but that's not what you really wanted to ask.

What you wanted to ask sounds more like "Can one app open another app in Android using an Intent?". The answer to that is also yes, but it has a few restrictions-  they must both be installed on the phone, they are separate processes so they can't share variables (except what you send in the intent), and you need to export the Activity you want to start in the manifest of the app its in.  Generally this isn't done except for calling preinstalled apps though-  you'd need your users to have installed two different apps, and they may not have done that.